# HTTP GET (with Header 'Connection: keep alive') over TCP

Tags: c#, http, sockets, tcp, get

I want to do the following with a raw C# socket. I understand that usually the most appropriate way is via HTTP, with a HTTP client. The browser understands that this connection must be kept open in some way.

`http://server.domain.com/protocol/do_something.txt`

I am trying the following in C#, but have had no luck. What am I doing wrong? Is there a header missing? Should I be encoding what I'm sending to the server in some way? For the ReceiverSocket client, I'm using the following code, but it's just a very standard asynchronous socket client: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10390066/971580

```
ReceiverSocket socket = new ReceiverSocket("server.domain.com", 80);
socket.Connect();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);            
String message = "GET /protocol/do_something.txt HTTP/1.1";
message += "\r\n";
message += "\r\n";
socket.Send(message);
```

The socket can connect successfully, but I don't get any response when I send anything to the server. This is how I am connecting, sending and receiving.t (Apologies: I tried to do this in snippets, rather than including all the methods, but it looked horrid. . .)

```
    public ReceiverSocket(String address, int port) : base(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    {
        messageQueue = new Queue<MessageBase>();
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(address);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        this.BeginConnect(remoteEP, ConnectCallback, this);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Connect Callback - Connected");
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;
                state.BufferSize = 8192;
                if (SocketConnected != null)
                    SocketConnected(client);

                client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, state.readOffset, state.BufferSize - state.readOffset, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Connect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Reconnect();
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Never gets here. . . ");
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
                foreach (MessageBase msg in MessageBase.Receive(client, bytesRead, state))
                {
                    // Add objects to the message queue
                    lock (this.messageQueue)
                        this.messageQueue.Enqueue(msg);
                }


                if (DataRecieved != null)
                    DataRecieved(client, null);

                client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, state.readOffset, state.BufferSize - state.readOffset, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
            }
            else
            {
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Reconnect();
        }
    }

    public void Send(String msg)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = GetBytes(msg);

            if (this.Connected)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + msg);
                this.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, 0, SendCallback, this);
            }
            else
            {
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException sox)
        {
            Reconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int i = 0;
        }
    }


    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
    }

    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public int readOffset = 0;
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        private int bufferSize = 0;
        public int BufferSize
        {
            set
            {
                this.bufferSize = value;
                buffer = new byte[this.bufferSize];
            }

            get { return this.bufferSize; }
        }

        private byte[] buffer = null;
        public byte[] Buffer
        {
            get { return this.buffer; }
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't the fact that I haven't included the `message += "Connection: close"` header mean that the socket should just start sending whatever data it has asynchronously? Just to note also: I can connect successfuly using Telnet and send the data, just not with a socket yet!

Any pointers at all would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't send `\r\n`, just send `\n`.  Per the HTTP 1.1 RFC, you also need to send a `Host` header: _A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages_

Comment: Why not use `WebClient` class? Why raw sockets?

Comment: If there is no reply after sending `"\r\n\r\n"`, then there may be something wrong with that `ReceiverSocket` class that prevented it from truly sending the message.

Comment: @SeanBright The RFC2616 that you mentioned also states the use of `\r\n` as the end-of-line marker for all protocol elements except the entity-body. And even though the `Host` header isn't present, that would still make the server reply with `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: @TarbhJohnnyDick, so, why not use proper abstraction? I am out of curiosity, what is the reason?

Comment: Query strings should not impede the server from replying to an HTTP request. I advise you to recheck `ReceiverSocket`. Can we also know what you are using to receive the response?

Comment: When @Serge says `WebClient`, he means `System.Net.WebClient`, which unless you have specific reason not to, I would also recommend you use. And nothing you've written so far says to me that you have any such reason. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: `System.Net.WebClient` does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4699045/17971

Comment: Then fire up Wireshark and execute that code to observe that WebClient uses HTTP Keep-Alive.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT call `Send()` until `ConnectCallback()` is called first, otherwise you risk sending your data prematurely.  Using `Sleep()` to wait for the connection is wrong.

Do NOT call `BeginReceive()` until after `Send()` has finished sending the data.

Because you are using HTTP 1.1, then yes, the connection is kept alive by default **if** you are connecting to an HTTP 1.1 server.  The server's `Connection` response header will indicate whether the server is actually keeping the connection open or not.

Also, as stated by someone else, HTTP 1.1 requests **MUST** have a `Host` header or else the request is malformed and can be rejected/ignored by the server.  HTTP 1.1 has a notion of virtual hosts running on the same IP, so the `Host` header tells the server which host the client wants to talk to.